# Set Offer Token using Flutter in app purchase package for Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-billing, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am trying to offer a subscription **with a specified [offer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973?hl=en#:%7E:text=Using%20Google%20Play%27s%20billing%20system,your%20app%20on%20Google%20Play.)** for specific users using Flutter in app purchases in the Google Play console.

I created an offer in Google Play Store with the "Eligibility Criteria" set to "Developer Determined", but I cannot figure out how to specify this offer in an in app purchase.

I am looking for something similar to the [setOfferToken](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.Builder#setOfferToken(java.lang.String)) method provided by the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/classes.html).

I thought that I could use the offer ID as a product ID from the [Google developer API docs](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/guides/products/product-id), but I had misunderstood the documentation.

I have looked through the Flutter [in app purchase package](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase-library.html) and the Google Play Billing Library, but could not find documentation related to my use case.

Is there any documentation specific to Flutter for assigning offer IDs to in app subscription purchases?

Thanks!